A quadrature rule given for this $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} f(t) dt = a_1 f(0) + a_2 f'(0) + a_3 f(t_3) + a_4 f(t_4) + R(f)$ using Gauss-Laguerre?
Can a Laguerre polynomial be used for this problem? How does $f'(0)$ square in?
Find coefficient and nodes for the following quadrature formula.
$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-t} f(t) dt = a_1 f(0) + a_2 f'(0) + a_3 f(t_3) + a_4 f(t_4) + R(f)$

What have you tried?

Is there some condition on $f$ you haven't told us? At minimum, it seems like you need the integral to converge, unless $R(f)$ can be infinity.

Nothing extra for $f$. The quadrature formula should have a high degree of exactness. I just wonder if Gauss–Laguerre quadrature can be used to approximate the above integral, considering the $f'$ on the right-side.

Did you try plugging $f \in {1,x,\cdots,x^4,x^5}$ to get $6$ equations for $6$ unknowns? If the quadrature is exact for these $6$ polynomials and due to linearity it is also exact for the first 6 Laguerre polynomials.

How did this required quadrature form arise?

That’s a shame, I liked this question.

As it was pointed out in comments, the standard way of computing the coefficients is to require that the quadrature rule has the highest possible degree. Considering that $\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-t} t^k \,dk = k! $, we get the system
$$
\begin{cases}
 a_1+a_3+a_4 =1\\ a_2 + a_3 t_3 + a_4 t_4=1\\ a_3 t_3^2+a_4 t_4^2=2\\
a_3 t_3^3 + a_4 t_4^3 = 6\\a_3 t_3^4+a_4t_4^4=24\\a_3t_3^5 + a_4 t_4^5=120 
\end{cases},
$$
which can be solved to get
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-t} f(t) dt \approx \frac{11}{18} f(0) + \frac 16 f'(0) +\frac{3}{8} f(2) + \frac{1}{72} f(6).
$$
This is not a Gauss-Laguerre quadrature, but the coefficients are computed in the same way.
